# SonarQube: Invoke method(s) only conditionally

Tags: java, logging, sonarqube

The following part of code raises a major bug at SonarQube : 
"Invoke method(s) only conditionally."
How am I supposed to fix this?

```
if(us != null){
    logger.info("Log this: {}", us.toString());
}
```

Comment: Can you turn off that inspection or do you need that for your project?

Comment: @QBrute I don't want to "Turn it off", I would like to know why this still raises a bug since an if() is applied which is one of the recommended solutions. AND/OR a solution.

Comment: Which logging framework do you use? Which version of SonarJava plugin on you SonarQube instance do you use?

Comment: Maybe sonarqube refer to "boolean isInfoEnabled()", you should use it. Which line is a major bug ?

Comment: @TiborBlenessy log4j 1.2.17 and sonar-maven-plugin 3.2 in case it will help anyone.

Comment: @BernardDubreuil This also worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The call to `us.toString()` is redundant, `toString()` method will be called regardless the configured log level. You should pass only `us` as an argument to `info` without an `if` statement.

```
logger.info("Log this: {}", us);
```

Comment: Is this answer really correct? In my case the warning is raised by using the same syntax in the answer.

Comment: @Funder can you share full code sample in gist or with some other online service? I can look into it

Comment: here we go @Tibor Blenessy https://gist.github.com/funder7/928484ff56b5db999d8472a931db14c4 . I've included the class received by the method, in case you need it. Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

As stated at the comments of the question, another working answer is:

```
if(logger.isInfoEnabled() && us != null){
    logger.info("Log this: {}", us.toString());
}
```

Comment: this is helpful

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. But doing this increase the cognitive complexity... I choose to disable S2629.

Answer (score 4):

You can just ignore this but it might be good to handle this scenario if possible, It would help us to handle and cutoff unnecessary computations.

One thing what it suggests here is to check if the Log Level that you are going to use is enabled or not.

```
if(logger.isInfoEnabled() && us != null){
    // this inner code will only get executed if the above is true
    logger.info("Log this: {}", us.toString());
}
```

Imagine having a complex task running inside, it would be a waste of time to do that if you are not going to log it anyways, if the log level is disabled. Logger will internally check that for you but doing it now before invoking the `.info()` will save you some cycles.

Answer (score 1):

It's related to performance issues. They recomend just putting a pure String or a final variable defined previously.

final var message = "Log this: " + us.toString();
logger.info(message);

https://sonarcloud.io/organizations/default/rules?languages=java&open=java%3AS2629&q=S2629

Answer (score 0):

Short easy answer: just delete the .toString from your code since the formatter will take care of changing it to String for you.

Answer (score -1):

Passing message arguments that require further evaluation into a Guava com.google.common.base.Preconditions check can result in a performance penalty. That's because whether or not they're needed, each argument must be resolved before the method is actually called.

Similarly, passing concatenated strings into a logging method can also incur a needless performance hit because the concatenation will be performed every time the method is called, whether or not the log level is low enough to show the message.

Instead, you should structure your code to pass static or pre-computed values into Preconditions conditions check and logging calls.

Specifically, the built-in string formatting should be used instead of a string concatenation, and if the message is the result of a method call, then Preconditions should be skipped altogether, and the relevant exception should be conditionally thrown instead.

Noncompliant Code Example

```
    logger.log(Level.DEBUG, "Something went wrong: " + message);  
// Noncompliant; string concatenation performed even when log level too high to show DEBUG messages
    
    logger.fine("An exception occurred with message: " + message); 
// Noncompliant
    
    LOG.error("Unable to open file " + csvPath, e);  // Noncompliant
    
    Preconditions.checkState(a > 0, "Arg must be positive, but got " + a);  
// Noncompliant. String concatenation performed even when a > 0
    
    Preconditions.checkState(condition, formatMessage());  // Noncompliant. formatMessage() invoked regardless of condition
    
    Preconditions.checkState(condition, "message: %s", formatMessage());  
// Noncompliant
```

Compliant Solution

```
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Something went wrong: {0} ", message);  
// String formatting only applied if needed
    
    logger.fine("An exception occurred with message: {}", message);  
// SLF4J, Log4j
    
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, () -> "Something went wrong: " + message); 
// since Java 8, we can use Supplier , which will be evaluated lazily
    
    LOG.error("Unable to open file {0}", csvPath, e);
    
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled() {
      LOG.debug("Unable to open file " + csvPath, e);  
// this is compliant, because it will not evaluate if log level is above debug.
    }
    
    Preconditions.checkState(arg > 0, "Arg must be positive, but got %d", a);  // String formatting only applied if needed
    
    if (!condition) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(formatMessage());  /
/ formatMessage() only invoked conditionally
    }
    
    if (!condition) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("message: " + formatMessage());
    }
```

Exceptions

catch blocks are ignored because the performance penalty is unimportant on exceptional paths (catch block should not be a part of standard program flow). Getters are ignored as well as methods called on annotations which can be considered as getters. This rule accounts for explicit test-level testing with SLF4J methods isXXXEnabled and ignores the bodies of such if statements.

Comment: It looks like fasle positive warning https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-3829

Comment: This answer is copy of `see Rule` which sonarqube suggests with the given issue.